# Copy value from one column to another and set to NULL - MySQL

Tags: mysql

In some cases I have to copy values from one column to another and set the first to NULL. This SQL-Statement works as expected:

```
UPDATE lessons SET order_id_old = order_id, order_id = NULL WHERE id = 1
```

But I'm not sure if this is a right way to do it so. Or should I better use 2 queries for this purpose?

```
UPDATE lessons SET order_id_old = order_id WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE lessons SET order_id = NULL WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: It's the right way. If you are not sure, duplicate it in a temp table and test it first.

Comment: If you do it with 2 statements, you should use a transaction to ensure atomicity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would definitely go with second approach. Here's what the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) says:

> Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to
>   right. For multiple-table updates, there is no guarantee that
>   assignments are carried out in any particular order.

In your case, it's fine at the moment as there is only one table. However, in future, if someone modifies this statement and adds a new `table`/`join` (assuming it'll work fine as it did with one `table`) it will stop working/give inconsistent results.

So, for the readability/maintainability purpose, go ahead with second approach. (Also, I would recommend wrapping both the `update` statements into a `transaction` to preserve [atomicity](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/definition/ACID))

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html):

> If you access a column from the table to be updated in an expression, `UPDATE` uses the current value of the column. For example, the following statement sets `col1` to one more than its current value:
>
> ```
> UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1;
> ```
>
> The second assignment in the following statement sets `col2` to the current (updated) `col1` value, not the original `col1` value. The result is that `col1` and `col2` have the same value. This behavior differs from standard SQL.
>
> ```
> UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;
> ```
>
> Single-table `UPDATE` assignments are generally evaluated from left to right. For multiple-table updates, there is no guarantee that assignments are carried out in any particular order.

In your case, it should be fine to use the single statement.